# Making and using NodeJS's soap client synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, synchronous

A using NodeJs's current soap client to call a soap service function whenever i send an HTTP request to the server.

The Problem is that the request returns before the soap service call finishes, thus returning no data.

The issues here is that the logic is asynchronous yet i need to make it synchronous.

Please kindly direct me to the right solution.

```
function soap_get_items(req,res){
    var resp = [];

    var soap = require('soap');
    var url = 'http://example.com/example.wsd?singleWsdl';
    var args = {name:"N.Hillary"};

    soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
        client.exampleSoapFunction(args, function(err, result) {
            resp = result;
        });
    });

    json_resp = JSON.stringify(resp);
    res.end(json_resp);
}
```

Comment: Node.js is one-threaded. World will stop while you will wait your synchronous soap response.

Comment: Just call `res.end(result)` in place where you get your answer.

Comment: Your code is *asynchronous*, this means that you will need to do all code relating to the `result` *inside* the callback.

Comment: @vp_arth my code logic depends on the data this function returns to continue to the next function. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should return the Promise and make things on its resolve. In node.js you must to think async :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to make it synchronous. You just need to just use the callback provided:

```
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
    client.exampleSoapFunction(args, function(err, result) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, this gave me a better understanding of how to work with it.

Comment: lol this moderator "H. Pauwelyn ツ" rejected my edit and re-did same himself and approved it himself, but made it worse. It's like a rep fraud :D